# Makefile compile all files with no target and no linking

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++

I would like to compile all .cc files in the current directory WITHOUT linking or having a target. All the examples I have seen assume you have an ACTUAL target file that you would like to output but I don't require anything other than having the resulting .o files sitting in the directory. I tried the code below with a fake target and got "undefined reference to main" and without a target I get the error "No rule to make target cc, needed by  o" - so far I have..

```
 CC= g++
 SRCS = $(wildcard *.cc)
 OBJS = $(patsubst $.cc, $.o, $(SRCS))

 $.o: $.cc
       $(CC) $(CPFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: The wildcard for patterns in a makefile is `%` not `$`. So you want `%.cc` and `%.o` in the `$(patsubst)` call and in the `%.o: %.cc` target.

Comment: ...And a non-pattern rule, something like `all: $(OBJS)`.